# Pandas: Filter rows depending on number of occurrences of target string

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Given this sample data:

| temp |
| --- |
| a. b |
| a b |
| a. b. c |
| ab.c |

I only want to keep rows in column `temp` that has only one period, so the above data would become:

| temp |
| --- |
| a. b |
| ab.c |

Is there a way to do this with a lambda function, preferably?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try this:

```
df.loc[df['temp'].str.count(r'\.').eq(1)]

   temp
0  a. b
3  ab.c
```

Answer (score 4):

```py
df[df.temp.str.count("\.") == 1]
```

Note that `Series.str.count` expects a regex.  So the `.` needs to be escaped, otherwise you will get the length of the strings.

Comment: Sorry I didn't see you posted this a bit earlier :)

Comment: @AnoushiravanR no worries, it's the obvious answer :-p

Answer (score 2):

We can use `apply` with the lambda function.

```
filt = df["temp"].apply(lambda x: x.count('.') == 1)
print(df[filt])
```